# How to connect to MongoDB using Spring Data

Tags: spring-data-mongodb

The official [tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mongodb/) seems to be missing on how to connect to MongoDB cluster?

Here are my requirements:

1. Using Spring Data MongoDB
2. Using Spring MVC (not Spring Boot)
3. Prefer using Spring Repositories

I am able to figure out how to create my repositories and the queries. But not able to wire the repository as a bean.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.my.TestRepository] found
```

Here is my Java based config:

```
@EnableMongoRepositories
public class RepositoryConfig extends AbstractMongoConfiguration {

@Override
protected String getDatabaseName() {

    return "test";
}

@Override
@Bean
public Mongo mongo() throws Exception {

    List<MongoCredential> credentials = new LinkedList<>();
    MongoCredential credential = MongoCredential.createCredential("test", getDatabaseName(), "test".toCharArray());
    credentials.add(credential);
    Mongo mongo = new MongoClient(new ServerAddress("localhost", 27017), credentials);

    return mongo;
}
}
```

And here is the way I am looping in my repositories:

```
@Autowired
TestRepository testRepository;
```

I have put the Java config file (above) and my `Repository` class in the same package.

Do I need to provide any additional configuration to be able to autowire the `Repository` classes?

Comment: We will need the code you used to wire it in. I'm assuming it was autowired?

Comment: Ok, will update with the code.